# Calculating Lean Angle with core motion of iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, core-motion

I am trying to calculate the lean angle/inclination of my iOS device.
I did a lot of research and found a way how to give me the most accurate lean angle/inclincation. I used quaternion to calculate it.

This is the code that I use to calculate it.

```
public void CalculateLeanAngle ()
    {           
        motionManager = new CMMotionManager ();
        motionManager.DeviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.02;  // 50 Hz

        if (motionManager.DeviceMotionAvailable) {
            motionManager.StartDeviceMotionUpdates (CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.XArbitraryZVertical, NSOperationQueue.CurrentQueue, (data, error) => {

                CMQuaternion quat = motionManager.DeviceMotion.Attitude.Quaternion;
                double x = quat.x;
                double y = quat.y;
                double w = quat.w;
                double z = quat.z;
                double degrees = 0.0;

                //Roll
                double roll = Math.Atan2 (2 * y * w - 2 * x * z, 1 - 2 * y * y - 2 * z * z);                        
                Console.WriteLine("Roll: " + Math.Round(-roll * 180.0/Constants.M_PI));
                degrees = Math.Round (-applyKalmanFiltering (roll) * 180.0 / Constants.M_PI);

                string degreeStr = string.Concat (degrees.ToString (), "°");
                this.LeanAngleLbl.Text = degreeStr;
        });
    }

public double applyKalmanFiltering (double yaw)
    {
        // kalman filtering
        if (motionLastYaw == 0) {
            motionLastYaw = yaw;
        }

        float q = 0.1f;   // process noise
        float r = 0.1f;   // sensor noise
        float p = 0.1f;   // estimated error
        float k = 0.5f;   // kalman filter gain

        double x = motionLastYaw;
        p = p + q;
        k = p / (p + r);
        x = x + k * (yaw - x);
        p = (1 - k) * p;
        motionLastYaw = x;

        return motionLastYaw;
    }
```

This works perfect when you walk and tilt your device. But when I drive my car something happens that the quaternion isn't giving me the correct lean angle/inclincation. It just gives me 180°.. Or suddenly it shows me a totally wrong lean angle/inclination.. Like when I am standing still (at trafic lights) it shows me 23°... Then after driving a bit it works again or it shows again 180°.

Could it be that the quaternion is effected by the acceleration of my car? So that because my car is driving at a certain speed it isn't giving me the correct value?

Does anyone have any solution for this? 
I would like to calculate my lean angle/inclincation when I drive my bike/car. So I really want to know how to calulate the right lean angle/inclincation independent if I drive my car/bike or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do have an acceleration when you are walking as well, even though considerably small. So I don't suppose *Acceleration* to be a reason.

Comment: Indeed, but then what could be the reason that it isn't working when I am driving?

Comment: Cannot compare the acceleration of a car to the acceleration of a walking person, but, the iOS device uses a sensor-fusion style calculus, so it uses a gyroscope, a magnetometer and an accelerometer to do these calculations. Maybe your car generates a magnetic disturbance when you accelerate, try to put your device on other place in your vehicle

Comment: I did try that. But i even got this problem when I drive my bike or when I drive an other car. So I don't think that the magnetic disturbance is the "real" problem.